# Issues with the type of double related to regional settings

Tags: c#, wcf, double, decimal, regional-settings

In my application (WCF, REST, .NET) in an object request I get a value of type double. I need this method to properly fulfilled on numbers with the decimal part "," and ".". How to arrange it without resorting to the type of string. For example: values "3,25" or "3.25" should be treated the same as the type of double.

example code:

this is a class that is used in the request object

```
[DataContract]
public class TripRatesMapped
{
    [DataMember(IsRequired = true)]
    public double Tolls { get; set; }

    [DataMember(IsRequired = true)]
    public double Parking { get; set; }

    [DataMember(IsRequired = true)]
    public double ExtraGr { get; set; }

    [DataMember(IsRequired = true)]
    public double Misc1 { get; set; }

    [DataMember(IsRequired = true)]
    public double Misc2 { get; set; }

}
```

and this is part of the request object

{
  "ExtraGr":1.25 ,
   "Misc1":1.26 ,
   "Misc2":1.27,
   "Parking":1.28,
   "Tolls":1.29
 }

I need so I can make a request in this form:

{
  "ExtraGr":1,25,
   "Misc1":1,26,
   "Misc2":1,27,
   "Parking":1,28,
   "Tolls":1,29
 }

whether this is possible without the use of type string?

Comment: Without giving more details about the context (application, programming language, operating system etc), it is difficult to answer your question.

Comment: What do you mean by "object request"? And if you are parsing numbers, then they must be strings, not doubles? Can you provide some example code?

Answer (score 1):

If you use the locale of the client you should be able to convert what they type into a double which you can use internally. You'll need to use the locale again when printing the value out.

Use this [`TryParse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3s27fasw.aspx) overload:

```
string value = "3,25";
NumberStyles style = NumberStyles.Number;
CultureInfo culture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("fr-FR");
if (Double.TryParse(value, style, culture, out number))
   Console.WriteLine("Converted '{0}' to {1}.", value, number);
else
   Console.WriteLine("Unable to convert '{0}'.", value);
```

If you omit the `CultureInfo` variable it will use the local culture to parse the text.

By including the `CultureInfo` you could build in some resilience by trying different cultures in turn until you either get a valid double or run out of options. The main drawback with this is that if someone makes a typing error or you check the cultures in the wrong order you could get the wrong number. If someone types "35,500" and you check the French culture first you'll get `35.5` rather than `35500.0`.

Comment: I think this WCF service doesn't use locale of client. On the contrary it accepts data from different locales and automatically binds them do doubles. So there should be a hint for binding to use invariant culture or something like that.

Comment: @AntonPalyok - The theory still holds - if the OP wants to accept input from different cultures he'll need some way of specifying it.